# Example code that handles the full game lifecyle properly

Tags: android

I am attempting to write an android game involving a class which extends SurfaceView and implements SurfaceHolder.CallBack. The class then creates its own thread which may need to be paused/unpaused appropriately. I wanted to use the example Lunar Landeras a reference, but this seems not to implement all sorts of essential things and it will occasionally crash on my phone.

What I am looking for is the **simplest possible** game which employs SurfaceView's, SurfaceHolder.CallBack's Threads and clearly handles all the game lifecycle events like onPause, onStop, onRestart etc - and without ever crashing.

Does such an example game exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some simple game examples on [apps-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/). Check SpriteMethodTest for example, which shows the basic structure of a good android game (what threads to create, how they communicate, how to draw efficiently (the app itself is a benchmark), ...). It implements both `SurfaceView` and `GLSurfaceView` and shows different ways to draw on these surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a game framework such as AndEngine ([www.andengine.org](http://www.andengine.org)). The message board has many examples for full games and also AndEngine handles many OpenGL aspects very simply.